# Extract Code from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

So I have a string in SQL like this

```
Declare @Denumire varchar(2000) = '''Name''name(109)'',''name (1921)'',''name name name name name (2312)'',''name name name name name (2358)'''
```

What I want is to retrieve every code for each Name .

For this example it would be

```
109,1921,2312,2358
```

I managed to get the last Code 2358 using the query.

```
Declare @Cod varchar(20)
    Declare @test varchar(3000) 
    declare @CoduriFinale varchar(2000)
    Declare @rDenumire varchar(3000) = REVERSE(@Denumire)
    SELECT @Cod = LEFT(@rDenumire,CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,@rDenumire , 0))
    SELECT @Cod = REPLACE (@Cod , '(' , '' )
    SELECT @Cod = REPLACE (@Cod , ')' , '' )        
    set @CoduriFinale = REVERSE(RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Cod,2,6))))+','
    set @test = SUBSTRING(@rDenumire,CHARINDEX (',',@rDenumire, 0),LEN(@rDenumire)) 
    set @rDenumire = @test
    print @CoduriFinale
    print @test
```

So what I did here, is revers the hole string ( this will make sure the first word) until a `' '` is my code, by I can't get it to work in a while loop for doing this for hole string.

PS : my string is in fact more strings separated by a comma.

Comment: T-SQL is atrocious at string manipulation, it would be easier to pass the data to the client then use Regex to extract the data. Of course, it would be better to do the parsing *before* storing denormalized data to the database. If you worry about tables with too many columns, you could use [sparse columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) to store hundreds of columns with minimal impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE   Function [fnRem](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', @strText), 1, '')
    END
    RETURN @strText
END






  Declare @test varchar(3000) 

    Declare @Denumire varchar(2000) = '''FABRICOM SYSTEMES D''ASSEMBLAGE (109)'',''VALEO VISION SAS (1921)'',''INERGY AUTOMOTIVE SYSTEMS GERMANY GMBH (2312)'',''TRW AUTOMOTIVE SAFETY SYSTEMS S.R.L. (2358)'''

    set @test =dbo.fnRem(@Denumire)

    select @test
```

**Output**
`109,1921,2312,2358`

Comment: Since SQL is a set based language, loops and [RBAR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx) should be avoided  as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try Stuff along with PATINDEX: something like below

[image]

Comment: I guess it is IDs next to the names so he wants a result set of IDs.

Comment: He wants a comma separated result set.

Answer (score 0):

Every string is already comma separated as you mention. Just use `REPLACE` function to replace all the below with a blank string ('')

`The string 'name', the apostrophes ('') and the brackets`

It would be kind of like multi-nested REPLACE functions.

When you apply the nested REPLACE functions, you would be left with the numeral comma separated string.

```
SELECT REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(@Denumire, '(', ''), ')', ''), 'name', ''), '''', ''), ' ', '')
```

Comment: This Won't work as name is what I've wrote here, but there are real names, anyway ty.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
DECLARE @alphaplace INT,@string varchar(200)='as678678df1234a1s2d3f4@@@'
SET @alphaplace = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string)
WHILE @alphaplace > 0
BEGIN
SET @string = STUFF(@string, @alphaplace, 1, ',' )

SET @alphaplace = PATINDEX('%[^0-9_,]%', @string)

END
select REPLACE(@string,',,',',')
```

Comment: For 'name (109)' the result is ,,,109, anyway ty, I've already found the solution.

Comment: I expected that the commas would play around with my code

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was unable to add my code. so added as image

```
OUTPUT
109,1921,2312,2358
```